# meaning of Nodelet

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what is meant by Nodelet  packages

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42598/meaning-of-nodelet/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [nodelet wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/nodelet). The wiki is always a good starting point to find information.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4